# Search through the whole project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Its a basic question I have a winform project having lots of file. I want to search a keyword through all the files with out opening each file. How can I do it?

Comment: The find dialog has that option...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  => Type what you want, by default it searches the whole solution.

[image]

Comment: You can change the "Look In:" target to "Project"

Comment: thinking of "Do search on these projects except these or this project"

Answer (score 9):

Hit `Ctrl+Shift+F` for the "Find In Files" dialog, then make sure that "Entire Solution" is set.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On the top of the solution explorer tab there is a search box

Answer (score 2):

Type "Ctrl + F" and select the option "Find all references". The result will appear in another window with all references.

Answer (score 2):

In visual studio search dialog you can specify the search scope:

Current document
All opened documents
Current project
Entire solution

Just pick the one more appropriate for you