# Why the VS find two definitions of function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In my solution,I want to look up the definition of function.Then interesting thing happened.

It tell me it find two definitions.

[image]

[image]

But one of its definition not belongs to my solution although there have similar code.

You can see one of it locate in `E://.....`,one of in `F://.....`

How to avoid this problem?

*PS:This project can compile and run correctly*

Comment: If the other file by the same name is really not part of the project, then I would be surprised that it is coming up in a project-scoped file search.  If this other file _is_ part of the project, then I don't think this is a bad thing.  Most of the time, you would want to see all matches from such a search.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The another file is really not part of this project.So it's funny

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search through the whole project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074195/search-through-the-whole-project)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen may be is different. He  want to search something in somewhere.Here is VS search something not belongs to current solution

Comment: Don't trust intellisense. It's really not bad but it's definitely not intelligent as the name might make you believe... ;-) (Btw. C++ is a really hard language concerning compiling and I'm really impressed what intellisense is meanwhile able to do.)

Comment: you mean it not a problem?ehh,OK.wish to see intellisense more smarter